# Transform skew messing with ul drop down

Tags: css, transition

I've skewed a top menu but it's having an affect on the sub menu as in when you hover, it appears but when you hover over the items, it disappears.

http://www.fi-testing.co.uk/birchfield/

Please look at 'Products'.

```
nav.top-bar {
    background: transparent;
}
nav.top-bar section ul#menu-topmenu li.menu-item {
    background: #2b80a7;
    text-align: center;
    zfloat:left;
  /* box-shadow */
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
    margin-right: 5px;
}

nav.top-bar section ul#menu-topmenu li a {
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
    -o-transform: skew(20deg);
    display: block;
    background: transparent;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav.top-bar section ul#menu-topmenu li:hover {
    background-color: #20556f;
}
```

The navigation works if the skew is removed from li.menu-item. I've tried adding skew: 20deg to ul.dropdown in the hope it would counter it, to no avail. Any pointers? Many thanks.

Comment: The issue isn't comming from the skewed elements (and therefore can't be reproduced with the code you are providing in the question), it's comming from the line of text under the menu. add `display:none;` to that line of text and you will see what I am talking about.

Comment: Thanks web-tiki for taking the time to reply. You're right, it's that text underneath. I hid it before to see if it was the problem, but it didn't change - I must of hid the wrong part. Thank you.